# JAXB | Google Sitemap w/ image:image-Tags using "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"

Tags: xml, image, namespaces, jaxb, sitemap

I'm trying to unmarshall given XML files, combine some information from these file and marshall them again, so that I can generate one single XML-file. But now I have a problem w/ my code since I had to change the namespace declaration from "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.9" to "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"

Before I had to change this, everything was correct and at the end I got XML like this:

```
<url>
    <loc>...</loc>
    <lastmod>...</lastmod>
    <changefreq>...</changefreq>
    <priority>...</priority>
    <xhtml:link href="..." hreflang="..."/>
    <uuid>...</uuid>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>...</image:loc>
    </image:image>
</url>
```

Now, after I had to change the namespace as mentioned at the beginning, all the image:image- tags are no longer in the final XML and it looks like this:

```
<url>
    <loc>...</loc>
    <lastmod>...</lastmod>
    <changefreq>...</changefreq>
    <priority>...</priority>
    <xhtml:link href="..." hreflang="..."/>
    <uuid>...</uuid>
</url>
```

Here you will find some code-snippets:

My package-info.java looks like this:

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns={ @XmlNs(prefix="", 
namespaceURI="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"),
            @XmlNs(prefix="image", namespaceURI="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"),
            @XmlNs(prefix="xhtml", namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
   }
)
package ....sitemaptools.xml;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

My XMLImage-Class:

```
package ....sitemaptools.xml;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement( name = "image")
public class XMLImage {

String loc;
public String getLoc() {return loc;}
@XmlElement( name = "loc", namespace="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1")
public void setLoc(String loc) {this.loc = loc;}

}
```

A part of my Node-Class:

```
List<XMLImage> imageList = new ArrayList<XMLImage>();
public List<XMLImage> getImage() {return imageList;}

@XmlElement(name = "image", namespace="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1")
public void setImage(List<XMLImage> images) {this.imageList = imageList;}

public void add(XMLImage image) {
    if (this.imageList == null) {
        this.imageList = new ArrayList<XMLImage>();
    }
    this.imageList.add(image);
}
```

If you need more information or snippets, just let me know and thanks in  advance!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this link https://www.kevinhooke.com/2014/03/25/debugging-jaxb-unmarshalling-issues/,  I managed it to get more debug information and figured out, that in my source XML files the URL for the Images changed from:

http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1 (http)

to

http**s**://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1 (https)

So I had to change this in my code and everything is working now.